# What is "él" for in "Estoy aquí porque me ha enviado él"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, gramática

I found this sentence which makes sense except for the last word `él`:

> Estoy aquí porque me ha enviado él.
>   I am here because he has sent me.

What is the `él` doing here? At first when I read it I thought it was saying `"I am here because he has sent me him".`

Is it there because it makes it clear that it is "he" who has sent for the speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact the `he` from `I am here because he has sent me.`. It would also be correct to write `Estoy aquí porque él me ha enviado`, spanish is specially flexible in the order of certain words.

If the context allows it (there is enough information preceeding), it might be omitted and written as `Estoy aquí porque me ha enviado`.

Your initial understanding of `I am here because he has sent me him` would have been written as `Estoy aquí porque me ha enviado a él`.

Comment: `Se los he dicho muchas veces.` Why is `se` being used in the beginning? Why isn't it just `los`? Wouldn't it make sense that way as well?

Comment: That's better off asked in a different question, as it's not related.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That sentence is also wrong, it would be "Se lo he dicho muchas veces". Lo is referring to whatever you've said to them, and it's singular. Please, open a new question for this

Comment: @pHonta Yes, it is wrong, but some latin-American countries actually use it.

Comment: @pHonta The translation for the one with `los` says "I've told them many times". Is that correct?

Comment: @Darkhogg I know, and we make many mistakes in Spain too (myself included). I thought it was necessary to point it out, though. You can speak perfect spanish while respecting the characteristics of the language, vocabulary, etc. of a particular region or country

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, but if you "correct" the mistake removing the "los", you get some ambiguity as you wouldn't know if it's "he/she" or "they". So it could either be "I've told him/her many times" or "I've told them many times"

Comment: Also, if you do not want to identify the person who invited you.  You can say `Estoy aquí porque se me ha enviado`... meaning, `I am here because I have been invited.`